# AD User to be granted logon to RDP server but not locally to clients

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I have a member of the "domain users" groups that has stopped working locally on client PCs and only needs to access the RDP server (which he already successfully can do).
So in order to stop this user from being able to logon locally on any client I went to AD and changed his account's "logon to..." property from "all workstations" to "only these" and entered the DNS name of the RDP server (like "CPY-K-TS1").
But now that user is denied RDP logon, saying s.th. like "the admin has limited the workstations you can logon to" (I am working on a german system, so I tried to translate messages and property names).

Now what?? Am I on the wrong track?

First thought was, well actually I do not want this user to logon locally to the RDP server, but only through RDP - so maybe I should leave the list of allowed workstations blank but AD doesn't allow that. The property ist automatically set to "all workstations" then.

Maybe I should mention that because of former necessities this user has a roaming profile. And granting of RDP logon rights comes from being member in an AD group which on the RDP server itself is given RDP access rights (so there are no RDP GPOs).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you want is to configure a GPO for each clients computers using [Deny log on locally](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/deny-log-on-locally) and [Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/deny-log-on-through-remote-desktop-services).

You can add a user or a group of user in these policies settings, and they won't be able to log on the computers where the GPO is effective (so don't apply this GPO on your RDP Server).

However, there is another way but I don't recommend it: Technically, [you can disable NLA](https://superuser.com/a/959932/708835) on your RDP server, and the "Logon To" thing will work as expected. However it less secure (the authentication will be processed directly by the RDP server instead of the clients, so you are more vulnerable to Denial Of Service attacks for example)